# Finding matrices with polynomials of an exact form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Might be a bad title here, but I am looking through some old prelim questions and am curious if someone may assist with this one:

***Find a list of real matrices, as long as possible, such that:***

1) The characteristic polynomial of each matrix $p(x) = (x-1)^{5}(x+1)$.

2) The minimal polynomial of each matrix is $m(x) = (x-1)^{2}(x+1)$.

3) No two matrices in the list are similar to each other.

Any tips? Is this leading to Jordan normal form?

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand the distinction between "characteristic polynomial" and "minimal polynomial"?  We can get the characteristic polynomial by subtracting, say, $\lambda$, from each number on the main diagonal and then taking the determinant which will be a polynomial in $\lambda$, the "characteristic polynomial".  It can be shown that every matrix makes its characteristic polynomial zero.
But, if the characteristic polynomial has repeated factors (so has repeated eigenvalues), we **might** be able to remove some of those factors getting a polynomial of lower degree that the matrix still makes 0.  That is the "minimal polynomial".  Yes, this has to do with the "Jordan Normal Form".  For example the matrices $A= \begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ both has "characteristic polynomial" $(3- \lambda)^2$. 
Both matrices satisfy that polynomial: $3I- A=  \begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}- \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $3I- B= \begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}- \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ both of which square to give 0.  But $3I- A$ itself is the 0 matrix while $3I- B$ is not.  That is, the "minima polynomial" for A is $3- \lambda$ while the "minimal polynomial" for B is $(3- \lambda)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

See *Frobenius normal form* and *similarity invariants*.

For any endomorphism $f$ of a vector space $E$ of dimension $n$ over a field $K$, $E$ can be seen as a finitely generated module over the ring of polynomials $K[X]$ through  $X\cdot u=f(u)$. It is a torsion module over this ring.

As $K[X]$ is a P. I. D., the $K[X]$-module $E$, by the *Fundamental theorem of modules over P. I. D.s* is a direct sum of cyclic submodules $\bigoplus_{i=1}^rE_i$, each $\;E_i$ isomorphic to $K[X]/(P_i)$, such that for all $i=1,\dots r-1, \enspace P_i\mid P_{i+1}$.

The sequence of polynomials $(P_1,\dots, P_r)$ characterises the endomorphism (or its matrix in a given base) up to similarity.

Furthermore, we know that $P_r$ is the minimal polynomial of the endomorphism $f$, and the product $P_1\dotsm P_r\;$  is its characteristic polynomial. Hence all you have to do is to find what are the possible steps to go from $P_r(X)=(X-1)^2(X+1)$ to $P_1$ with the above-mentioned constraints. Then, for each similarity invariants, you  can take as an example of a similarity class the block-matrix with each block equal to the companion matrix of the invariants.

Answer (score 1):

These are $6\times 6$ matrices because the characteristic polynomial is a sixth degree polynomial. There are two eigenvalues: $\lambda=-1$ and $\lambda=1$. The Jordan blocks with eigenvalue $-1$ must all be order $1$. The Jordan blocks with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ must have at least one $2$ block, but no larger.

Use $+$ to denote eigenvalues $1$ and use $-$ to denote eigenvalues $-1$. let $[\;\;]$ denote a grouping by block.
$$
\mbox{2 [++] blocks} \\
          [++][++][+][-] \\
          [++][++][-][-] \\
\mbox{1 [++] block} \\
          [++][+][+][+][-] \\
          [++][+][+][-][-] \\
          [++][+][-][-][-] \\
          [++][-][-][-][-]
$$